# MaxDeliveryCount on forwarding queues

Tags: azureservicebus

Is there any guidance on what the `MaxDeliveryCount` should be set when using auto-forwarding to another queue in ServiceBus?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Delivery count matters when receiving from an entity. When an entity is set to auto-forward messages, receiving is not possible. Which makes delivery count irrelevant.

Comment: Thought that it may matter if there are issues with SB preventing forwarded messages from being delivered to the target queue, and they would need to retry. Any thoughts on that?

Comment: Forwarding is guaranteed and doesn't rely on the deliver count. Delivery count is for the external consumers / client code.